# Finishing current activity after AlertDialog action throws an error

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-alertdialog

I'm having a problem with AlertDialog: if I want to finish the current activity after I open a new one, I get crashed with the following error:

`E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.myapp.ShowsActivity has leaked window DecorView@2435213[ShowsActivity] that was originally added here`

This happens when I want to log out a user. The AuthLogic.logout() method gets called (I exported it to a standalone class to have a more readable code) which triggers a "are you sure?" alert dialog which then redirects to login activity.
Logout button logic:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shows)

        // some code . . .

        btnLogout.setOnClickListener {
            AuthLogic.logout(this)
            finish() // *1
    }
}
```

AuthLogic.logout():

```
fun logout(context: Context) {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        builder.setTitle(R.string.are_you_sure)
        builder.setMessage(R.string.confirm_msg_logout)
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.confirm) { dialogInterface: DialogInterface, i: Int ->
                // aditional logout logic
                context.startActivity(AuthActivity.newStartIntent(context))
            }
            builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel) { di: DialogInterface, _: Int -> }
            builder.show()
        }
```

I noticed that the error pops up if I finish my activity on *1 comment. If I remove that line, no error gets shown, but this causes a problem because I can go back to the previous activity and I don't want that. I already tried using `dialogInterface.dismiss()` on `setPositiveButton` lambda method, but no success. Any ideas?

**EDIT! solved!:)**

I rewrote AuthLogic.logout():

```
fun logout(context: Context) {
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            builder.setTitle(R.string.are_you_sure)
            builder.setMessage(R.string.confirm_msg_logout)
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.confirm) { dialogInterface: DialogInterface, i: Int ->

                // logout logic ...
                dialogInterface.dismiss()
                context.startActivity(AuthActivity.newStartIntent(context))
                (context as Activity).finish()
            }
            builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel) { di: DialogInterface, _: Int -> }
            builder.show()
        }
```

and removed the finish() line seen on *1.
Thanks to @Johan Kovalski for the tip.

Comment: Finish the activity after clicking on confirm button of the alert dialog, not on just showing dialog.

Comment: What that error is basically telling you to to dismiss alert dialog before finishing the activity

Answer (score 1):

Try to dimiss your alert dialog before finish the activity.

yourAlertDialog.dimiss();

Answer (score 0):

Dialog `Window` is created with activity `Context`. `Activity` has to cleanup windows that it owns. You should destroy dialog first, then activity. Or use `DialogFragment`.

Log you mentioned in question tells you that activity cannot be properly destroyed (as you requested with `finish()`) because dialog still holds reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

This can also solve the problem

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34259602) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).